# How do I manage TTL of Kotlin Dispathers.IO threads

Tags: java, multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have noticed weird behavior of Dispatchers.IO thread pool.

I have a periodical type of load in my system. Once a minute it consumes hundreds of events which are being handled by coroutines running on Dispatchers.IO thread pool.
Official docs tell us, that

> "Additional threads in this pool are created and are shutdown on
> demand"

But as I can see TTL of the threads between creating and shutdown in my case is 1 minute. By the way, it looks exactly like default setting of java's `Executors::newCachedThreadPool`. Which is so much weird in my opinion. Creating threads instead of reusing them is a notorious antipattern. But this is what exactly is going on here.

Actually I have no problems with memory leaks and GC in general, but anyway it looks suspicious.

[image]

The question is. Is it ok? If not - how can I tune TTL (or keep-alive) for threads from Dispatchers.IO thread pool?

Kotlin version: 1.7.0
kotlinx-coroutines-core version: 1.6.1

Comment: Dispatchers.IO will create as many threads as needed to process all incoming tasks as fast as they arrive.  If you don't want that behavior, don't use Dispatchers.IO.  (Really, don't use any of the Dispatchers.Anything except Main on some circumstances...)

Comment: Actually not "as many" but only 64 by default. And this fact is visible on the chart. The question is about TTL of this threads, not about its total number.